# Cant deploy project on vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel

I am getting the following error when I try to Deploy my next.js project on Vercel,

```
Build Failed
No Next.js version could be detected in your project. Make sure `"next"` is installed in "dependencies" or "devDependencies"
```

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "ecommerce",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.4",
    "@next/font": "13.3.1",
    "@sanity/client": "^5.4.2",
    "@sanity/image-url": "^1.0.2",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.52.1",
    "canvas-confetti": "^1.6.0",
    "next": "13.3.1",
    "next-sanity-image": "^6.0.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
    "stripe": "^12.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "eslint": "8.39.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.3.1"
  }
}
```

I have updated all my dependencies to the lastest versions.
I have tried deleting the node_modules folder from the directory and running npm install.
Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Is it a public repository?